# Como retornar que um recurso "não foi encontrado" no Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Estou fazendo uns testes no Spring para retornar erro 404 caso ele não encontre um `id` ao buscar no repository, mas está dando 200 OK.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> buscar(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Optional<Livro> livro = livrosRepository.findById(id);

    if(livro == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(livro);
}`
```

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Que tal trocar o if pra if(!livro.isPresent())? Seu atributo livro é um Optional, e bem provável que ele não seja null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vejo dois jeitos de fazer o que você quer:

1 - Igual ao que o @Tom Melo comentou

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> buscar(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Optional<Livro> livro = livrosRepository.findById(id);

    if(!livro.isPresent()) { // Mudança aqui
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(livro);
}
```

Deste modo você usa o método isPresent do Optional

2 - Ou deste outro modo

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> buscar(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Livro livro = livrosRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);//Mudança aqui

    if(livro == null) {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(livro);
}
```

Deste modo você espera retornar um Livro e se não achar ele vai ser null, pela sua linha de pensamento este me parece mais apropriado mas os dois métodos vão fazer a mesma coisa no fim

Comment: Deu certo! Era isso mesmo o objeto não é nulo. Obrigado a todos pelo auxílio!

Comment: Que bom, lembre de aceitar a resposta

Answer (score 3):

Seu código pode ficar mais declarativo usando os métodos do `Optional`, sem a necessidade de um `if`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> buscar(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
    return livrosRepository.findById(id)
      .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
      .orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
}
```